# Firebase & firebase-admin: There is no configuration corresponding to the provided identifier

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-admin

I've inherited a client project that uses Firebase for notifications and I'm trying to figure out who the admin user is (so that I can get an invite to the Firebase project).

All I have, is a firebase certificate in the following JSON format that I found on the client's AWS ("..." = redacted):

```json
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "...",
    "private_key_id": "...",
    "private_key": "...",
    "client_email": "...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "...",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "..."
}
```

I thought I could use firebase-admin to get a list of all users:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: 'https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com',
    credential: admin.credential.cert(require('./firebase.json')),
})

;(async () => {
    console.log(await admin.auth().listUsers(100))

})()
```

But doing so I get the following error:

```
(node:77972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: There is no configuration corresponding to the provided identifier.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (.../firebase-test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (.../firebase-test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (.../firebase-test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:149:16)
    at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (.../firebase-test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:188:16)
    at .../firebase-test/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:1665:49
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async .../firebase-test/firebase.js:10:14
```

What does this error mean? Is the credentials JSON incorrect? It seems to be in use on AWS to send notifications.

Any other ideas how I can get a login email from a JSON like the one above?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should check that the path to the JSON file containing your Firebase credentials is correct and that the JSON file is valid and contains all the required fields. Additional error handling can be added to the code using `try/catch` blocks to catch any errors that might occur. You can also verify the validity of the JSON file by using a JSON validator tool or the `JSON.parse` method in Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue; problem was "Authentication" needs to be enabled in firebase.

Login to firebase and click "All products", click on "Authentication" and get it connected.

Though judging from question it should be viewable, meant that authentication is already an existing app. Do check the credentials that was used to initializeApp, or if problem persist just login to firebase -> authentication and view the users instead.